# Kubernetes ingress priority and unhealthy services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

We are in the process of transferring a bunch of services from an old platform to Kubernetes. To try to make this as transparent as possible to the users, we've added a catchall ingress that routes all unmatched traffic to the old platform's host. This allows the users to switch to the new host immediately, and gradually as we migrate more of our services (with specific ingresses matching their paths) the Kubernetes cluster serves more of the load.

One problem we have run into though is how to handle singletons that can't run on both platforms simultaneously. In these cases we need to shut down the service on the old platform and start it up on Kubernetes within a relatively short amount of time.

We have an idea to do this via an init container, where we deploy the Kubernetes singletons with an init container that waits until it gets a signal from the old platform that the service is stopped before allowing the pod to start. But as it turns out, during the time when the pod is waiting for the init container to start up, the service's ingress will take effect and cause the host to return 503 errors instead of falling back to the catchall ingress as we would like it to.

Is there anything I can do to configure the ingress to not take effect (and defer to a lower-priority ingress) if its service is unhealthy?

We are using Traefik as our ingress controller.

Comment: Can you provide more details on this "singleton"? What's blocking you from deploying both legacy and k8s and do runtime switching?